# What does @Mock do? Can I use it with @BeforeClass?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

This throws NPE in `beforeClass()` because `o` is null:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FooTest {
    @Mock
    private static Object o;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        when(o.toString()).thenReturn("foo");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        o.toString();
    }
}
```

However, if I make it a non-static `@Before` method, it passes. If instead of using `@Mock` I write `= mock(Object.class)`, it passes.

This seems strange. Is there anything I'm missing about `@Mock`? If its only purpose is to save you from writing `mock(MyClass.class)` (while forcing you to add `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`), but it prevents you from using `@BeforeClass`, it seems like an unnecessary element that should be deprecated. Or is there something I'm missing that would allow me to use both these elements?

Comment: Having a static mutable field in a test class is odd.

Comment: @tgdavies Nothing strange about setting up static mocks to be used in several tests. Also, having a static mutable list which is cleared in the `@Before` method may be preferable to creating a new list each time, if that list is to be used as the `thenReturn()` value of a static mock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, if I make it a non-static @Before method, it passes. If instead of using @Mock I write = mock(Object.class), it passes.
> This seems strange. Is there anything I'm missing about @Mock?

`@Mock` is just an annotation that marks fields as being mock objects. *Something* has to fill in those fields with mocks. Per [the documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.8/org/mockito/Mock.html), you can do that with `MockitoJUnitRunner` or with `initMocks`.

If you do it with the runner, as you have illustrated, then your mocks will only be ready after the runner executes and in Mockito runners execute before each test but *after* the class has been initialized.

> If its only purpose is to save you from writing mock(MyClass.class) (while forcing you to add @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)), but it prevents you from using @BeforeClass, it seems like an unnecessary element that should be deprecated. Or is there something I'm missing that would allow me to use both these elements?

You are trying to use an API that seems to be designed for *instance* fields on a *static* field. So it's not "unnecessary", it's just not applicable to your use case.

The easiest thing to do for your case would be to remove the `RunsWith` annotation and <strike>call `initMocks` as the first call in your `beforeClass` method</strike> just mock the object inline, as you already indicated: `o = mock(MyObject.class)`.

Comment: Seems to require non-static context: `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`

Comment: Ah, of course. The inline mocking is your best option then. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

@Mock and Mockito.mock(MyClass.class) both have the same function. The main difference is that @Mock is considered by most as cleaner.

There are different points to mention in your tests:

- @BeforeEach require to use static fields and static methods as the methods executed in it are done during the initialisation phase, meaning before creating instances of classes.
- @Mock is executed after @BeforeClass, that why those annotations don't work together (the mock is not yet created when executing BeforeClass).
- Using Mockito.mock(MyClass.class) forces to create the mock during the execution of the method annotated with @BeforeClass, this is why it works.